# Software Center doesn't open (Loki)

Tags: release-loki

I tried reinstalling software center (after `apt update`) and got errors.

Notice that some Loki Release repositories do not have a Release file.

I upgraded Freya to Loki. I noticed numerous errors in the log about not having permissions, as well as the missing release files in Update Manager.

Here is the syslog output:

```
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .debfile import DebFileApplication, DebFileOpenError
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/debfile.py", line 25, in <module>
    from softwarecenter.db.application import Application, AppDetails
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/application.py", line 28, in <module>
    import softwarecenter.distro
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/__init__.py", line 201, in <module>
    distro_instance = _get_distro()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/__init__.py", line 176, in _get_distro
    module = __import__(distro_module_name, globals(), locals(), [], level)
ImportError: No module named "elementary"

One: "Input error: No module named "elementary"
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all the only way to upgrade Freya to Loki is to reinstall elementaryOS. So if you didn't fresh install Loki I suggest you to do so, to prevent errors like this one to happen.

Second, in Loki the Software Center was removed to give place to AppCenter.

Comment: I did an install over Freya. The icon for Software center still shows in the dock and in the menu. Would it help to repeat the installation?

Comment: As I told you earlier, you have to reinstall, which means make a backup of whats important to you and when installing Freya format each partition before installing Loki. That's is the only and official way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Having no software center and not being able to get Synaptic Package Manager is like having arms and legs chopped off. We don't all use phones for Internet, quite a lot of serious users use a desktop. What's the point of having to mess with terminal to get the things that you need after installation?
I have to go back to Ubuntu until I find an opsys I am happy with. The things I like are pantheon look and the old Midori. I shall miss those